# OWIN Google authentication - how to get id_token?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-authentication, identityserver3

I have things set up so that I am able to successfully authenticate using Google. Code looks like something along these lines:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Google",
    Caption = "Sign-in with Google",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
    ClientId = "yyy",
    ClientSecret = "zzz",
    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnAuthenticated = async context =>
        {
            // How can I access id_token here?
        }
    }
});
```

When the Authenticated method is invoked I have access to all kinds of info about the user via the GoogleOAuth2AuthenticatedContext. However, I need to be able to read the raw id_token from Google so that I can add it to the claims and have access to it later on in the authentication flow. Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you're using the 3.0.1 bits, as the initial 3.0.0 version doesn't include the `TokenResponse` property you need for this scenario.

Then, update your `OnAuthenticated` notification to extract the identity token from the token response:

```
var token = context.TokenResponse.Value<string>("id_token");
```

To resolve the "OpenID identifier", you can use the JWT security token handler to extract the claims from the identity token:

```
var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);
var identifier = jwt.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => string.Equals(claim.Type, "openid_id", StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: You were right, I was using the 3.0.0 version of Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google. 3.0.1 works beautifully as far as giving you access to the token. Thanks!